# Android/Gradle - Include transitive dependencies only

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

Is it possible in an Android/Gradle project to include only the transitive dependencies of a particular module, without including that module itself?

For illustration, say there's a module `X` that has transitive dependencies on `A`, `B`, and `C`.  I want my project to have `A`, `B`, and `C` on the classpath, but *not* `X`.  Ideally what I want to do is leverage the fact that `X` already knows what dependencies I want, so that I don't have to explicitly declare dependencies on `A`, `B`, and `C` in my project.

Hypothetically, what I want is something approximately like:

```
implementation(group: 'com.x', name: 'Xlib', version: '1.0', ...){
    transitive true                         //include 'A', 'B', and 'C'
    exclude group: 'com.x', module: 'Xlib'  //exclude 'X'
}
```

...as in "nominate `X` as a dependency, grab its transitive dependencies, and ignore all top-level packages from `X`".

Is there any way to do that or is it necessary to explicitly declare `A`, `B`, and `C` as dependencies?

Comment: Good question. My use case for this is: I have a dependency that I'm including in a shadow jar, but I don't want to include transitive dependencies in the shadow jar, I want them to be specified as dependencies of the shadow jar.

Answer (score 4):

I have done this [here](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-monkey-patch/blob/master/java-monkey-patch/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/JavaMonkeyPatchPlugin.groovy#L46-L77) in my `java-monkey-patch` plugin where I want to include all the transitive dependencies of a `target` artifact but not the `target` artifact itslef

```
dependencies {
    monkeyPatchTransitive target
    monkeyPatchNonTransitive target
    compileOnly(target) {
        transitive = false
    }
}

Set<Map>  depSet = [] as Set
ResolvedDependency topDependency = configurations.monkeyPatchTransitive.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies.iterator().next()
topDependency.children.each { ResolvedDependency child ->
    child.allModuleArtifacts.each { ResolvedArtifact artifact ->
        ModuleVersionIdentifier mvi = artifact.moduleVersion.id
        def dependency = [
                group  : mvi.group,
                name   : mvi.name,
                version: mvi.version,
                ext    : artifact.extension
        ]
        if (artifact.classifier) {
            dependency['classifier'] = artifact.classifier
        }
        depSet << dependency
    }
}

depSet.each { Map dependency ->
    logger.info "Adding $dependency"
    dependencies.compile(dependency) {
        transitive = false
    }
}
```